# Xcode 6: "Archive validation failed with error" "Invalid image path"

Tags: ios, validation, swift

I'm trying to validate my app to distribution but I'm getting this error:
[image: error message]

The strange thing is that in my info.plist file I have an empty dictionary in the "CFBundleIcons" key:

[image: info.plist file]

[image: info.plist file raw value]

I know there are similar questions posted but this case is a little particular also this is my app icon source:

[image: AppIcon]

Anyone have any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: did u add app icon of size 120 *120?

Comment: Yes, I did it in the app Icon source and I checked it in the finder an the image is in the right path

Comment: not about the path..u need to add app icons of different sizes like 58*58, 87*87, 120*120, 180*180 etc..take the app icon..copy paste it on your desktop..change their sizes as said above..then drag each of the icon to the matching size in xcode app icon image.

Comment: yeah like you can see in the image I posted I already added all the image in their respective sizes

Comment: issue solved? or still the same error?

Comment: solved with the @Vamshi Krishna answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I encountered this problem once. Try this.
Select your app icon and uncheck the CarPlay option.[image]